# Book series involving stones that give different abilities

Tags: story-identification, books

In the series people use stones that give them powers. Each stone gives different abilities and leaves marks on the user after long term use.

In one of the books they discover that the stones are actually the hearts of these stone creatures that have died. Every night the users have to refill the stones power by drawing it from the sky.

In one book the heroine finds the most powerful stone called "lashabhala", or something like that. In another I believe the son of the heroine from the first book has a stone that allows him to find anything, and in the next book he gives his stone to his daughter but, instead of finding things, it gives her the power to call dragons.

Comment: That's a good start, but some more information would be useful.  How long ago did you read this series?  Do you have any idea how many books are in the series?  What language and country did you read the books in?  Were they hardcopy or ebooks?